# How to change the language of the navigation voice of the HERE sdk depending on the language of the phone

Tags: android, kotlin, here-api, here-android

I am using the [HERE sdk](https://developer.here.com/) to make a navigation application.

What I want to achieve is to put the language of the navigation voice in the language in which the mobile phone is, for example, if the language of your phone is in English, the instructions say them in English, if it is in French, the voice is in French. I have researched the HERE sdk documentation but [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/map-voice-instructions.html) is the only thing I have found and I can't find any way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the link I assume you use the Premium edition. For the Navigate Edition, you can check this link: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/1886956dc86b4f5efa9be06ef213ab2e42226d81/examples/latest/navigate/android/Navigation/app/src/main/java/com/here/navigation/NavigationExample.java#L511 Basically, you can get the language of the phone with Locale localeForCurrenDevice = Locale.getDefault(). Then you need to check if this locale is supported by the SDK and the TTS engine. I assume, this can also be done in a similar way for the Premium Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Before download you can use VoicePackage.isTts(), it should be false(it means that it does not require TTS engine) or after voice package has been downloaded check if voice skin output is AUDIO and not TTS:

```
List<VoiceSkin> skins = VoiceCatalog.getLocalVoiceSkins();// in loop
OutputType type = skin.getOutputType(); // should be AUDIO.'
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/api_reference_java/index.html?com%2Fhere%2Fandroid%2Fmpa%2Fguidance%2FVoicePackage.html

supported voices :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/dev_guide/topics/coverage-navigation-voices.html